# Why did meta-transaction fail to garner adoption

Tags: openzeppelin, smart-contract-wallets, meta-transactions

Open Zeppelin had an initiative to allow meta-transactions through their gas station network https://docs.opengsn.org/ but it failed to materialize.

There was also eip-2770 https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2770, that seeked to standardize a generalized forwarder meta transaction. It has failed to get any transition.

Enabling gas-less transaction seems like a nice feature to have. Why have meta-transactions failed to garner adoption and do you think there is a future where they will work?

Comment: I can think of two issues: the transaction have an extra cost, you don't pay directly in ether but in some other toke, and you also have to pay the intermediary; it requires modifications to existing contracts, some contracts like token are kinda easy to modify but large contracts require extensive modifications and likely audits. Also layer2 alternatives became more popular.